# Entity Framework not saving data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, guid

I have a model which contains the following property:

```
public Guid UniqueID
{
    get { return Guid.NewGuid(); }
}
```

If I examine the object after it is created, I can see that a new guid is correctly created for the `UniqueID` field.

However, when I call `db.SaveChanges()`, I get an error back from Entity Framework stating that it cannot insert NULL into this field despite there being a value present.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

```
private Guid _uniqueID = Guid.NewGuid();
public Guid UniqueID
{
    get
    {
        if(_uniqueID == null){
            _uniqueID = Guid.NewGuid();
        }
        return _uniqueID;
    }
    set
    {
        _uniqueID = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you really want to get a new GUID _every time you access the property_?

Comment: Yes as there is an issue at the moment with duplicated objects into database, which we are currently trying to diagnose and fix, but need a temporary workaround. This is the best way to ensure the records are unique for a temporary situation like ours

Comment: ID's for an object should not change.  If you want a new ID for each object, create a private field that is initialized to a new GUID value.  Getting a new ID every time you access the property is very odd and may be causing the behavior you are experiencing.

Comment: Do you mean for instance: `private Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();` and then return id in the get accessor?

Comment: That would work better.  Plus you need a setter - EF does not support get-only properties; otherwise there's no way for EF to set the value when loaded from the database.  You can make the setter `private` if you want to prevent updates from outside of EF.

Comment: I have updated the question. is there an issue with that edit? If it works, put it as an answer and i will accept it

Comment: This seems to have worked. Thanks for your help @DStanley if you put it as an answer i will accept it for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF does not support get-only properties.  There needs to be some way for EF to be able to set the value when loading form the database.  You can use a private setter if you want to make the field immutable:

```
private Guid _uniqueID = Guid.NewGuid();
public Guid UniqueID
{
    get
    {
        return _uniqueID;
    }
    private set
    {
        _uniqueID = value;
    }
}
```

Note that this is slightly different from your edit.  I have made the setter `private` and have taken out the `if(_uniqueID == null)` since a `Guid` is a value type and can never be null.